# Fill 2 different lists with .filter

Tags: angular, typescript, list

I am working with Angular 13 in a project where I have to populate a PickList component (it is a simple PrimeNG component, link is [here](https://primefaces.org/primeng/picklist)).

The way we work with this component is simple. We receive from the backend a list of columns and the user has to select some or every single column in order to create a DataTable (also a PrimeNG [component](https://primefaces.org/primeng/table/dynamic)). Next, I am providing some code to show how we do it.

**Column.ts**

```
export interface Column {
  field: string;
  header: string;
  type: string;
  format: string;
  editable: boolean;
  widthColumn?: string;
}
```

**column.service.ts**

```
getColumns() {
    return this.http
      .get<any>(url)
      .toPromise()
      .then(res => <Column[]>res.data)
      .then(data => {
        return data;
      });
  }
```

**picklist.component.ts**

```
  sourceColumns!: Column[];
  targetColumns!: Column[];

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.columnService
      .getColumns()
      .then(columns => (this.sourceColumns = columns));
    this.targetColumns= [];
  }
```

But now, the backend has changed, and they added a new field, which is `required`, like this:

```
export interface Column {
      field: string;
      header: string;
      type: string;
      format: string;
      editable: boolean;
      widthColumn?: string;
      required: boolean;
    }
```

So now, by default, I have to fill those lists depending on if the column is required or not, with this criteria.

- If the column is required, push to **targetColumns**
- If the column is not required, push to **sourceColumns**

What I have tried so far:

```
this.columnService
      .getColumns()
      .then(columns => (this.allColumns = columns));

    let nonReqCol = this.allColumns.filter(column => column.required == false)
    let reqCol = this.allColumns.filter(column => column.required == true)

    this.sourceColumns= [...nonReqCol]
    this.targetColums= [...reqCol]
```

But it gives me this error on console:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')
```

I can not figure it out why this is giving me this error, since I am doing (as far as I know) the same thing on both scenarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
this.columnService
      .getColumns()
      .then(columns => {
           this.allColumns = columns;
           this.filterColumns();
       ));

// ...
private filterColumns(): void {
    const nonReqCol = (this.allColumns || []).filter(column => column.required == false)
    const reqCol = (this.allColumns || []).filter(column => column.required == true)

    this.sourceColumns= [...nonReqCol];
    this.targetColums= [...reqCol];
}
```

Basically you are filtering columns but they are not defined yet.

Comment: Your problem initially is you are retrieving your data with a Promise returned by your service (getColumns), and you assign the result of this promise to the allColumns variable. However, you are filtering just after asking your service to fetch the data without waiting the response. So 2 options, you can do what I suggested, adding a filter function inside the `then` section, or use async/await statements (see: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

Comment: Just applied what you said and works fine. Thankyou so much